# C# using DataDirectory in connection string with variable filename

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am new to C# and have been working on a program for work. A simple ticketing program as a backup when the primary goes down. I don't have a server to run a database on so I have been using sqlite. This works great since I don't need to install anything. I would like to set it up to save the database file for each users program to save to a network location with a unique name for the database file. I have figured out how to set the save location of the database but not give the file a name. I would like to use the name of the current logged in user which is already unique and displays when the program runs, it is also added to the database when a new ticket is saved. The program checks the file location and if the database does not exist creates it.

```
public partial class Ticket_Contingency : Form
{

    SQLiteConnection con;
    SQLiteDataAdapter da;
    SQLiteCommand cmd;
    DataSet ds;
    DataTable dt;
    int id;
    string userName = Environment.UserName;
```

}

```
    public Ticket()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));
```

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //loads the saved username from App.config
            usernametextBox.Text = userName;

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Properties.Settings.Default.folderdb);

        dblabel.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.folderdb;
        //Diables Autovalidation
        this.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;

        if (!File.Exists("|DataDirectory|incidentdb.sqlite"))

            try
            {
                con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|incidentdb.sqlite;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

                con.Open();

                cmd = con.CreateCommand();

                cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE 'contacts' ('Id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0) ,'firstname' VARCHAR,'lastname' VARCHAR,'mi' CHAR,'email' VARCHAR,'phone' VARCHAR,'ext' CHAR,'visn' CHAR,'site' VARCHAR,'department' VARCHAR,'desklocation' VARCHAR,'notes' VARCHAR,'template' VARCHAR,'priority' CHAR,'summary' VARCHAR, 'status' CHAR, 'timestamp' DATETIME NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'username' VARCHAR)";

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();

                Form1_Load(this, null);
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                // Log the exception
                {

                }

                //Tries to connect to the local Database. Returns error message on failure
                try
                {
                    con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|incidentdb.sqlite;Version=3;");

                    con.Open();
                    da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select ID, firstname as 'firstname', lastname as 'lastname', summary as 'summary', timestamp as 'timestamp' from contacts ORDER by ID ASC", con);
                    ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "Person_Details");
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    con.Close();
                    Clear_Form(this, null);

                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    Application.ExitThread();
                }
            }
    }
```

What I would like to do is replace

```
        if (!File.Exists("|DataDirectory|incidentdb.sqlite"))
```

with something like

```
        if (!File.Exists("|DataDirectory|" + userName + ".sqlite"))
```

I know that doesn't work but I really have no idea how to go about this. I have searched everywhere but can only come up with results that look like the original code
            if (!File.Exists("|DataDirectory|incidentdb.sqlite")

I would really appreciate some help. Like I said I am new to this. Most of my other issues were solved with research but this is beyond me.  Thanks!